# InflateException When Trying to Load Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to load a fragment from my activity and am getting the an error as below:

```
07-25 21:09:53.221 31245-31245/kitchenpal.troychuinard.com.kitchenpal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: kitchenpal.troychuinard.com.kitchenpal, PID: 31245
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{kitchenpal.troychuinard.com.kitchenpal/kitchenpal.troychuinard.com.kitchenpal.IndividualRecipeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:742)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.isSupportFragmentClass(Fragment.java:404)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3679)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:114)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:374)
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:39)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:68)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:777)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:412)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2414)
    at kitchenpal.troychuinard.com.kitchenpal.IndividualRecipeActivity.onCreate(IndividualRecipeActivity.java:15)
```

I understand it may have to do with the support library that I am using for my fragment manager.

```
public class IndividualRecipeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecipeStepsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_individual_recipe);

    if (savedInstanceState == null){


        RecipeStepsFragment recipeStepsFragment = new RecipeStepsFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.recipe_list_fragment, recipeStepsFragment)
                .commit();

    }
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

     }
}
```

Fragment:

```
 public class RecipeStepsFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public RecipeStepsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment RecipeStepsFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static RecipeStepsFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        RecipeStepsFragment fragment = new RecipeStepsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recipe_steps, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/recipe_list_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</fragment>
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to specify a `Fragment`'s class name on a `<fragment>` element in the `activity_individual_recipe` layout. You don't need a `<fragment>` element if you're loading it dynamically. Use a `<FrameLayout>` instead.

Comment: The accepted answer on the linked duplicate exactly explains your situation.